# MVC3 prevent navigation away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I prevent a page not to navigate away when a link on the page is clicked. I have the code bellow but it instead shows a message twice. The page also has a data grid. The message that pop ups is shown twice only when i navigate away from the page by click a record on the grid. Anywhere else its fine.

```
   var canShowWarning = "@(Model.CanEdit)";
var showWarning = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (canShowWarning && showWarning) {
        return 'You have made unsaved changes';
    }
}
$(function () {
$("#Form").submit(function () {
        showWarning = false;
    });

    $("#Form").change(function () {
        showWarning = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: So, when you submit the form you should not navigate to any other page ? Am i right ?.

Comment: Not really. Im trying to prevent any navigation in the page. When I navigate away with links in the grid the popup is shown twice but when i navigate with other links in the page it shows once.

Answer (score 0):

```
var canShowWarning = "@(Model.CanEdit)";
var showWarning = false;
var alreadyShown = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (canShowWarning && showWarning && !alreadyShown) {
        alreadyShown = true;
        return 'You have made unsaved changes';
    }
}
$(function () {
$("#Form").submit(function () {
        showWarning = false;
    });

    $("#Form").change(function () {
        showWarning = true;
        alreadyShown =  false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The message is still shown twice if i navigate away by click the data grid records. The grid records are links